# Change default terminal in files (io.elementary.files)

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon-terminal, dconf

I just switched to Kitty and I'm loving it, but when I open a terminal in the files app always send me to the default terminal instead of kitty.

I have modified the default launch terminal via:

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec kitty`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg ''`

In the dconf editor can't find any option related to the default terminal.

Also can't find kitty in the "open with" list.

Comment: Do you have a desktop file "kitty-open.desktop" in `usr/share/applications` ?  The current source code appears to provide this and it should allow Kitty to appear in the "Open with" list.  Probably best to enquire at https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/discussions/ how to get full desktop integration.

Comment: I found a solution, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

After following the Jeremy suggestion.

Just add this desktop entry to **/usr/share/applications**. The name should be different from **kitty.desktop** so this entry will only work for the "open with" menu. I named it kittyt.desktop.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=kittyT
Exec=kitty --directory %f
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;
Type=Application
Icon=kitty
OnlyShowIn=
```

Change the name for whatever you want, the important values here are the Exec, that launch the terminal in the actual directory and the OnlyShowIn that hides the icon from applications menu.